# Is the term "strawberry spring" something made up by Stephen King for the short story?

Tags: stephen-king

In the short story [Strawberry Spring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strawberry_Spring) by Stephen King, which in my opinion has enough hints of the supernatural to qualify for this site, the "strawberry spring" of the title is a false spring, much like an [Indian summer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_summer) is a false summer. The story links this strange weather to a string of seemingly [supernatural](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring-heeled_Jack) and unexplained murders.

Did Stephen King make this up, or does something called strawberry spring really exist (without the murders, of course)? A cursory search seems to return no hits other than the short story, and Mr King's fans [seem to think it's his own invention](https://stephenking.com/xf/index.php?threads/strawberry-spring-a-real-term-or-an-invented-one.188/). Is that so?

Comment: A quick glance at Google Books suggests that the term didn't exist prior to the publishing of King's story. It *might* be a colloquialism that somehow failed to be noted by linguists, but it seems more likely that King just made it up out of whole cloth

Comment: @Valorum Yes, I think he made it up too. But I'm not a native English speaker (I didn't know about Indian summer either), so just double-checking here ;)

Comment: I'll have a hunt around for an interview or a quote.

Comment: I've asked Stephen. If he responds, I'll let you know.

Comment: It might be something like Ray Bradbury's "rocket summer" (from *The Martian Chronicles*).

Comment: https://news.google.com/articles/CBMiVGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmRldm9ubGl2ZS5jb20vbmV3cy9kZXZvbi1uZXdzL3N0cmF3YmVycnktbW9vbi0yMDE5LXRvbmlnaHQtaGVyZXMtMjk4NTQxMtIBWGh0dHBzOi8vd3d3LmRldm9ubGl2ZS5jb20vbmV3cy9kZXZvbi1uZXdzL3N0cmF3YmVycnktbW9vbi0yMDE5LXRvbmlnaHQtaGVyZXMtMjk4NTQxMi5hbXA?hl=en-GB&gl=GB&ceid=GB%3Aen - strawberry moons are a thing..m